# Не меняется размер шрифта в документе HTML в sublime text3

Tags: html

Всем привет! 
Сегодня установил на windows10 sublime text3 и во время установки необходимых плагинов не смог самостоятельно уменьшить размер шрифта именно в документе index.html хотя в preference - setting - уменьшил fons size на 12, но в документе index.html все равно шрифт остается большим. Для сравнения при изменении шрифта в настройках он сразу меняется в main.css[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на старом ноуте на windows7 через настройки в preference меняется шрифт везде, а в 10-ом никак не могу пофиксить

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в закладку `Preferences` в раздел  `Settings - Syntax Specific`

В правой колонке укажите `"font_size": 12,`, где цифра - размер шрифта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]